# Observable in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to understand the Observer and the Observable.

Here's an example that I'm trying to figure out:

```
public class IntegerDataBag extends Observable implements Iterable<Integer> {

    private ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void add(Integer i){
        list.add(i);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator(){
        return list.iterator();
    }

    public Integer remove (int index){
        if (index< list.size()){
            Integer i = list.remove(index);
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
            return i;
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public class IntegerAdder implements Observer {

    private IntegerDataBag bag;

    public IntegerAdder(IntegerDataBag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
        bag.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (o == bag) {
            System.out.println("The contents of the IntegerDataBag have changed");
        }
    }

}
```

1. The `bag.addObserver()` can be made only because `IntegerDataBag` extends `Observable`?
2. Where is this observer being add to? What is being created and where?
3. What is the difference between `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()`?
4. I don't understand the `update` method; what does `arg` stand for? Why do I need to check that `o==bag`? Why would I update another observable?
5. Why should I need this observer anyway?

Comment: This is one of the few patterns which can only be best understood when you comes to the point you *really* need to use one in your existing project.

Comment: Like in MVC for example. Give this code a try: http://www.emilmont.net/doku.php?id=java:design_patterns:model_view_controller

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes. `addObserver` is a method in the `Observable` abstract class. See [Observable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) in the Java documentation.
2. It is added to  a list in `Observable`.
3. A call to `notifyObservers` will do nothing until `setChanged` is set.
4. You might have multiple Observables in the same application.
5. `Observer` is a common design pattern. The usual example is when you have a Model and multiple Views. Each View is an Observer on the Model; if the Model changes, the Views get updated.

Comment: From memory, Observable is an asbtract class and not just an interface. Also setChanged is used like a flag I think. This is to avoid unnecessary updating. The args can be used as a parameter. Look up Listener as this approach is also used in Java.

Comment: @James Poulson, Observable is **not** an abstract class at all (in the JDK).

Comment: You're right, it's actually a normal/concrete class. As this article states this differs from the implementation of other design patterns which rely on interfaces/asbtract classes: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=156

Comment: Its not abstract but you need to create a inheritable class to use protected setChanged method

Answer (score 6):

Let's take a practical example for Observer pattern: Twitter. With Twitter we can *follow* some other people and read whatever they post in near realtime.

Every twitter user is *observable*. You can add yourself as a listener ("Follower") and read his/her posts. Every twitter user will do a "notify Followers" (`notifyObservers`).

Here we do the same. The class `IntegerDataBag` has the capability to notify other classes whenever a value is added to or deleted from it's internal bag. Any instance (that implements `Observer`) can register itself to an `IntegerDataBag` and will receive messages through it's callback method (`update`).

In short, we do the following:

1. A *observer* (listener, `IntegerAdder`) adds itself to an *observable* (`IntegerDataBag`)
2. Something happens at the *observable* and the *observable* notifies its *observers*
3. The *observable* will call the callback methods of all actual *observers*
4. The *observer* now has been notified of the event and can use it

Hope, this short description helps in understanding this pattern.

---

publish/subscribe is a similiar pattern: a publisher is like an observable, a subscriber like an observer. And another practical example: one can subscribe to a newspaper and the publisher will send the paper until you cancel your subscription.

Comment: And whats the difference between Observable/Observer and Publis/Subscriber pattern?

Answer (score 5):

> **The bag.addObserver() can be made only because IntegerDataBag extends
>   Observable?**

Correct, `Observable` is a class that has the `addObserver()` method.

> **Where is this observer being add to? what being created and where?**

The `Observer` class contains a `List` or `Vector` (in the JDK source) of `Observable` objects.

```
private Vector obs;
```

That's where it's stored.

> **What is the different between `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()`?**

The `setChanged()` just marks the `Observable` is changed.
The `notifyObservers()` just calls the all observers it has on the list to `update()` (passing a changed object to the Observer) only if the `setChanged` is set to true.

> **I don't understand the update method- what does args stands for? and
>   why do I need to check that o==bag, why would I update another
>   observable?**

The `update()` method tells the `Observer` that it needs to update based on the changed `obj` it receives. This is called by the `notifyObservers()` from `Observable`.

> **Why should I need this observer anyway?**

To create a `Listener` for event driven scenario, i.e. if you want to be informed in the change of your observable objects, then Observer is needed.

Read: GoF - [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 4):

> The bag.addObserver() can be made only because IntegerDataBag extends
>   Observable?

Yes.

> 2.Where is this observer being add to? what being created and where?

Into the related Observable class, which your class is extending.

> 4.I don't understand the update method- what does args stands for?

It's called when the state of an observed object has changed.
The args is the parameter passed to nofityObserver.

> and why do I need to check that o==bag, why would I update another
>   observable?

You don't need to check anything.

> 5.Why should I need this observer anyway?

It's a very useful design pattern. Have a look to wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

EDIT:
I missed point :

> What is the different between setChanged() and notifyObservers()?

setChanged() marks an object signalling that it changed. notifyObservers is responsible to wake all observer listening to the observable object.

Answer (score 3):

> The bag.addObserver() can be made only because IntegerDataBag extends Observable?

Yes, the `addObserver` method is implemented in `Observable`.

> Where is this observer being add to? what being created and where?

The observer is being added to a list of observers which is declared in `Observable` as private, so it is not visible in your subclass.

> What is the different between setChanged() and notifyObservers()?

When you call `notifyObservers()` without first calling `setChanged()`, no notifications take place.

> I don't understand the update method- what does args stands for? and why do I need to check that o==bag, why would I update another observable?

One `Observer` can watch multiple `Observables`. By examining the first parameter of the `update` method, you can figure out which observer is notifying you about something.

> Why should I need this observer anyway?

Any time you want a class to send events to other classes but you don't want a direct dependency from that class on its observers.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your points.

1. Yes you're correct
2. The observer is added to a list maintained in the Observable object
3. You need to call setChanged() before you notify observers, otherwise they won't know the object has changed. Once you call notifyObservers(), All obvserers are notified of the change. If you don't call setChanged first, your observers won't be notified.
4. arg is anything you'd like to pass to Observers when you call notifyObservers(arg);

Answer (score 2):

The observer pattern is similar to the concept of listeners. The object which is being listened to maintains a record of all of it's listeners. For instance, a stock monitor class may allow objects to listen for a certain event, such as the stock level falling below the warning level.

**From the observer's point of view:**

Call `subscribe()` or `addEventListener()`or the like. The observer is then "notified" when the event actually occurs, usually by means of calling a function in the observer (the event handler function).

**from the observable's point of view:**

Objects wishing to observe the observable object register their interest by calling the `subscribe()` or `addEventListener()` as above. The observable thus adds these observers to an array, list, or some other data structure.

Once the event actually happens, the listeners are notified by calling the event handler function in the observers' class.

Answer (score 2):

The update() method is called by the Observable. This method is called by calling notifyObservers(), which itterates trough all Observers and calls update on them. This informs the Observer that the object they are watching has been changed and a certain action can be performed. 
The args object is whatever you want it to be, it can be null aswell but it can be used to inform the observers what type of update just took place.

Answer (score 2):

> The bag.addObserver() can be made only because IntegerDataBag extends Observable?

Yes, that's the whole point.

> Where is this observer being add to? what is being created and where?

It adds `IntegerAdder` to the list of classes that observe `IntegerDatabag` for changes. From now on, if a change occurs on `IntegerDataBag`, it will notify `IntegerAdder` via the `notifyObservers()` method, which will trigger its  `update()` method.

> What is the difference between setChanged() and notifyObservers()?

`notifyObservers()` calls the `update()` method of every observer of your observable, and is used to pass infos to this method. As for `setChanged()`, it marks your object as "changed" so that the `hasChanged()` method will now return true... It's used to monitor changes to your observable class.

> I don't understand the update method- what does args stands for?

The `update()` method is inherited from the implementation of the observer interface - You have to implement it. The `Object arg` is an optional argument that you can pass to the method via `notifyObservers()`.

> Why do I need to check that o==bag, why would I update another observable?

Since an observer can "observe" more than one "observable", you need to check that it's really `IntegerDatabag` that triggered `update()`, hence `o==bag`.

> Why should I need this observer anyway?

You need the observer to monitor `IntegerDataBag` for changes. In your case, you print a message in the console when `IntegerDatabag` is modified. The purpose of the Observer/Observable model is specifically to monitor changes on specific objects, and then update the program based on the changes.