# Java, how to detect when a attribute of an object has changed

Tags: java, event-handling

I can't get from the java documentation if it's possible to listen for a change in object's attribute value. Let's say my object has only one int attribute field. I need to perform an action in the moment, my object changes its state. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a variable has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401527/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-has-changed)

Answer (score 6):

You want to look into observers/observables in Java. They will allow you to do what you need.

There is a lot online about it.

Here is a little stub: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html

More here: [When should we use Observer and Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/when-should-we-use-observer-and-observable)

Comment: Your answer seems to be what I need, but after I imported Observable and extend my class with Observable, It still reports me that setChanged() method must be defined. Observable is not the to be extend by my class

Comment: @AlessandroSassi You need to define setChanged() to be able to notify observers. There is some more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271044/observable-in-java and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

Comment: I did not properly expressed in my premious comment, I yet extend a class in my class, and cannot extend Observable also...

Comment: @AlessandroSassi Could you give some more detail of your implementation? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a class which runs on localhost where Objects are constructed, with RMI I access the method of the object on the server class from a client class. I need to print on the console output of the server class a notification string when the client class has accessed the object's methods and modified attributes of the object.

Answer (score 1):

If this object isn't yours and you are looking for an event listener of sorts for the property of an object, no, there are no object property listeners.

But, if you can modify the source of the object, I assume you are using getters and setters. So, you'd have something like...

```
public void setIntegerValue(int num){
    this.num = num;
}
```

The most efficient thing to do is to add some sort of logic inside the setter to execute your function when the integer `num` is changed:

```
public void setIntegerValue(int num){
    this.num = num;
    yourFunction(); // Let your program know that num has been modified
}
```

Comment: problem here is you'll have to do it for every setter in the class. If a later programmer adds a new setter and doesn't know about this, things break. There is no way to just detect any changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a setter method you can add calls to other methods.

First, make your property private.

```
private int myProp;
```

Then, add a setter.

```
public void setMyProp(int myProp) {
    boolean isVariableChanged = myProp != this.myProp;
    this.myProp = myProp;
    // do other things
}
```

In this case, if the variable changed, the boolean in the method will be true, which can be used if you want to prevent triggering the method if the variable is changed back to its current value.

You will then also need a getter.

```
public int getMyProp() {
    return myProp;
}
```

Generally, getters and setters are recommended to make code more maintainable when the implementation of a class changes.

However, they also give you the ability to use getters and setters as pseudo listeners.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to call a method on an object which is on a server, so with RMI I can see the effect of the mehod invocation on my client console, but I also need to display something on the server console

Comment: Do you have access to the code on the server? How is that variable set?

Comment: Yes I access the code for the server since it's a trivial experiment I'm doing to understand certain things. The variable I'm listening for is set private

Comment: Ok then at some point you must be calling a setter method to set the value of the variable on the server side. When that method is called, you can call other methods from your setter.